# Is a single HTTP operation atomic?

Tags: http, tcp

Is a single HTTP operation atomic?
Today I have a meltdown in my brain working on some weird behaviour of my application.

For example two clients are sending a Post operation to the server listening on port 443.

Is the scenario below possible?:

1. Client 1 sends request to the server
2. Server receives Client 1 request
3. Client 2 sends request to the server
4. Server receives Client 2 request
5. Server sends response to Client 2
6. Server sends response to client 1
7. Client 2 receive response
8. Client 1 receives response

It drills down to the TCP/IP protocol I would guess.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this is related to atomic operations. Web servers typically start multiple threads per request, and can respond in any order. They don't block new requests/responses for existing ones. The lifecycle of each individual request in singular/atomic; they shouldn't access state of each other.

Comment: Yes it is possible. The server won't normally sequentialize the calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, not at all - it drills down to an implementation detail. HTTP operations are atomic in as far as the code processing them makes them so. TCP per se says nothing about that - so the question as is can not be answered.

Comment: Sorry I should not insert the bit about TCP/IP.  So the POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, and DELETE are atomic and the scenario I have described is not possible. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Nope. I say that if you have 2 overlapping requests (remember processing time) whether or not they are atomic has NOTHING to do with HTTP and EVERYTHING to do with the competence or lack thereof of the programmer writing the processing code.

Comment: So I have to write the code that is atomic and protects the sharing resources from being accessed by different threads executing the operations, right?

Comment: @JanuszDalecki That is correct.

Comment: @ user207421 One last question. The `HttpContext` will be unique for each separate request will it not?

Comment: You mean, we read the documentation for you?

Comment: @JanuszDalecki there is no such thing as `HttpContext` in TCP or HTTP, that is entirely an implementation detail of your particular HTTP server. So it is up to the server whether it decides to use unique contexts or share them. Read its documentation or ask its author.

Comment: Actually given that .NET is open source - read the source IS asking the author.

Comment: Thanks guys for all your contributions. It is very clear to me know what I wanted to know.